# How to enable Espresso Test Recording

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, ui-testing, android-espresso-recorder

As of yesterday's Google IO Keynote, there seems to be a major update in the way we do UI testing in our projects.

Automated testing is about to see a huge step forward thanks to a new test recorder feature. Developers will be able to start a recording and start using their app. As each action is performed, it is turned into Espresso code that can be played back across a number of platforms, including Google's Cloud Test Lab. This will likely cut time to write tests to a tenth of what it took in the past.

I installed the latest version of Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 and I am wondering what should I do to enable this feature.

Comment: could you post the link to that keynote

Comment: Check out this blogpost: http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/05/18/android-studio-2-2-preview-announced-with-a-new-layout-designer-test-recording-with-auto-generated-espresso-code-and-much-more/

Comment: Check this:https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html

Comment: There's a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210478. Vote for it by clicking on the star. It'll come, just not right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate but accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318922/espresso-test-recording-feature-in-android-studio-2-2

Comment: if you want play with http://droidtestlab.com/. I use it and it works pretty well. What are your thoughts @Vyacheslav Pedak?

Comment: @war_Hero This is the video where they were showing the functionality 
https://youtu.be/csaXml4xtN8?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8jQTUYvIfqA9lMvSGQWtte&t=1346

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's finally there! Android Studio 2.2 preview 3 (available [here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio22preview3available))

Be aware that any existing openened projects will be converted and might not be able to be openened again with older versions! (They do create a backup of the project)

<strike>You can stop looking for now.
It's not in 2.2 preview 1 and neither in 2.2 preview 2.
Fingers crossed for Preview 3</strike>

> Unfortunately the Espresso Test Recorder is still not in this build; we're addressing a few more issues and then hope to have it ready in the next build!
>
> Not until Preview 2 or 3. No dates yet. So I hear,
> https://twitter.com/JeremMartinez/status/733548682075721728. It would
> be interesting to see how many people have tried to find the feature
> and was unable to find so far.

Answer (score 4):

It was shown in the talk today as being listed under the Run menu option.  But, it is not.  Hopefully, it will be updated soon.

Answer (score 2):

The Espresso test recorder has been released in Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3.

Instructions to download:
https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio22preview3available

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version of Android Studio i.e. Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3.

After downloading, in the toolbar go to **Select Run/Debug Configuration** which is present to the right of Make Project  button. In the Run/Debug Configuration, select **app**. Then go to the Menubar and inside the Build menu you will find an option **Record Expresso Tests.** Click it and enjoy the ease of testing.

Comment: It is missing. No such menu.