# Android Studio 2.2 preview Record Espresso Test option not available

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have seen Google Keynote 2016. This is link to [**Video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csaXml4xtN8)

So I was excited about Espresso recorder.

I am not able to see the **Record Espresso Test** option in run menu.

#### I am using Android studio 2.2 preview 1.

Below Screen shot is from video.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to be a duplicate of this question:
[Espresso test recording feature in Android Studio 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318922/espresso-test-recording-feature-in-android-studio-2-2)

Short answer: It seems that this feature was, possibly unintentionally, left out of this release.

**Edit: Great news, preview 3 of Android Studio 2.2 contains the Automatic Espresso test. [See Android Studio Project site](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio22preview3available).**

Comment: Android 2.2 preview 2 is out but still no espresso recoding. Hopefully they will include in next iteration. http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview2available

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2

**Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3 is out now**

This build contains New features and a number of fixes for various critical bugs found in preview 2:

**Espresso Test Recorder**
Demo of the Espresso Test Recorder shown at IO is now included in Preview 3

**See [updated change log](http://tools.android.com/recent)**

### Update 1

**Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2 is out now**

> Unfortunately the Espresso Test Recorder is still not in this build;
> we're addressing a few more issues and then hope to have it ready in
> the next build!

---

**They haven't provided the Espresso Test recorder with Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1**

**See this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210478) for more information**

> It looks like this was intentionally left out and won't be included
> until preview 2:

### Original

**As Suggested by @marcel50506**

Also this see [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318922/espresso-test-recording-feature-in-android-studio-2-2)

Answer (score 1):

Espresso test recorder is finally out in **Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3**, which is available as of now!

It does work quite decently, with the exception that you still can't run and test only a specific activity, but it rather starts from your main activity every time. But surely a very good starting point!