# "Record espresso test" option is not enabled in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-testing

The "Record espresso test" option is greyed out in Android Studio.

What are possible reasons for this?

I have installed the Espresso test dependencies and I have an emulator running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable Espresso Test Recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316679/how-to-enable-espresso-test-recording)

Comment: No, I did see that post but it is a very old post relating to a time when Espresso test recorder was just being released

Comment: I just updated to Android Studio Iguana in the last week, seems to me that's when I started seeing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

I thought it's because we need to do the proper setup first (gradle-wise), so I did. No change.
Then I thought maybe we need to already have a build configuration for instrumented tests first. Did it, no change.
Then I thought maybe we need a first test to exist already. Did it. No change.

Note that AS shows Espresso Test Recorder as enabled in the plugin, and at launch, the option is available in the menu, it's only after the IDE loading is finished that it becomes unavailble.

It seems like Espresso isn't available for Compose, could it be your issue?